# "Illegal arguments: string, undefined" while logging in the user

Tags: mongodb, express, authentication, mongoose, schema

I am trying to login user with correct credentials but it's giving me an error saying "Illegal arguments: string, undefined". This one is my function to log in the user:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const User = require('../model/userModel');

const loginUser = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    //check for user by email
    const user = await User.findOne({ email})

    if(user && (await bcrypt.compare(password.toString(), user.password))){
        res.json({
            _id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email, 
        })
    }else{
        res.status(404)
        throw new Error('Invalid email or password!')
    }

})
```

this is my userModel.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please add a name']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please add an email'],
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please add a password']
    },

},{
    timestamps:true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Comment: The user model doesn't have a `password` field, you define `name` twice.

Comment: thanks i fixed that, but it's still giving me that issue

Comment: Adding `password` to the schema does not alter the documents already in the database. Any documents you inserted will need to have their `password` set.